# Performance for PostgreSQL with datafile mounted on NAS

Tags: postgresql

I'm interested is there someone tried to run PostgreSQL server with datafile mounted on NAS server via iSCSI?

Are there any performance issues? Can you share some information?

Comment: Yes, I had a mount point provided to my database server because I did not have enough space. But I faced performance on many levels including my backup plan, application front end and running complicated queries. But I have tried some performance tuning and parameter tuning of postgresql according to best practices and it got a little better. but overall I would recommend using internal storage mechanisms.

Comment: @Sayad When did you tried this? I'm interested with 10GB direct connection what will be the results.

Comment: I tried this about month ago, But revert back and used a storage instead of NAS. But still I have a NAS and taking my manual backups (pg_dump) through that which is still slow than taking backup in the internal storage. If you are running an application with small size and is used for other than OLTP databases then it should not be a problem.

Comment: What about database performance? Do you face a huge bottleneck using NAS?

Comment: Not a huge bottleneck but the query response time was slower than using internal storages

Comment: Which would make sense. A single SSD is around 6 gigabit - 10g is quite slow compared to an array of SSD (which is the standard for high performance these days), which likely is why pro solution now use 100gigabit for storage connection ;)

Comment: Can I ask either of you how you got this to work, I'd like to test but when I try I get an error about incorrect permissions which should exist as I think I've given the necessary permissions for that folder on my NAS